# Handle Daylight Saving Time on SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-2, dst

Hi is there a function on SQL Server that can identify if Daylight Saving Time  is active or not.

where i created a scalar function that converts the server time to plant location  time who uses the application upon insert/update is executed.

the problem is i did not know that there is DST on US. So my plan is i will do something like

```
if DST is active
   // -1
else
  // + 1
end
```

where i need to check if DST is active or not

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: When multiple time zones are involved, I'd usually recommend storing all `datetime`s as UTC, and doing any necessary conversions in client software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling Daylight time Function:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_GetDaylightSavingsTimeStart]
(@Year varchar(4))
RETURNS smalldatetime
as
begin
declare @DTSStartWeek smalldatetime, @DTSEndWeek smalldatetime
set @DTSStartWeek = '03/01/' + convert(varchar,@Year)
return case datepart(dw,@DTSStartWeek)
when 1 then
dateadd(hour,170,@DTSStartWeek)
when 2 then
dateadd(hour,314,@DTSStartWeek)
when 3 then
dateadd(hour,290,@DTSStartWeek)
when 4 then
dateadd(hour,266,@DTSStartWeek)
when 5 then
dateadd(hour,242,@DTSStartWeek)
when 6 then
dateadd(hour,218,@DTSStartWeek)
when 7 then
dateadd(hour,194,@DTSStartWeek)
end
end

CREATE function [dbo].[fn_GetDaylightSavingsTimeEnd]
(@Year varchar(4))
RETURNS smalldatetime
as
begin
declare @DTSEndWeek smalldatetime
set @DTSEndWeek = '11/01/' + convert(varchar,@Year)
return case datepart(dw,dateadd(week,1,@DTSEndWeek))
when 1 then
dateadd(hour,2,@DTSEndWeek)
when 2 then
dateadd(hour,146,@DTSEndWeek)
when 3 then
dateadd(hour,122,@DTSEndWeek)
when 4 then
dateadd(hour,98,@DTSEndWeek)
when 5 then
dateadd(hour,74,@DTSEndWeek)
when 6 then
dateadd(hour,50,@DTSEndWeek)
when 7 then
dateadd(hour,26,@DTSEndWeek)
end
end

declare @DLSStart smalldatetime
, @DLSEnd smalldatetime
, @DLSActive tinyint
set @DLSStart = (select MSSQLTIPS.dbo.fn_GetDaylightSavingsTimeStart(convert(varchar,datepart(year,getdate()))))
set @DLSEnd = (select MSSQLTIPS.dbo.fn_GetDaylightSavingsTimeEnd(convert(varchar,datepart(year,getdate()))))    
if @Date between @DLSStart and @DLSEnd
begin
set @DLSActive = 1
end
else
begin
set @DLSActive = 0
end
select @DLSActive
```

Comment: "link only" answers tend to be frowned upon. There's no guarantee that the link will be alive (in an hour, tomorrow, next year)